# COM Port Commands CRC XOR

Tags: delphi, serial-port, delphi-7

I have a **check printer** that I want to connect in **Delphi 7** by **COM port** and operate.

I have a command that I extracted with Serial Port Monitor:

**STX "PIRI(781" FS NULL ETX "0B"** wich is **02 50 49 52 49 28 37 38 31 1c 00 03 30 42** hex

The manual says the following:

> CRC (which is the last two digits after the ETX) - packet checksum. It
>   is calculated by the following algorithm:  executing XOR for every
>   byte of the block including ETX by excluding STX.  The data of the
>   checksum take up two bytes and are a symbolic representation of the
>   numeric in a hexadecimal calculation system.

I tried to an ONLINE CRC calculator and return a 1B result and a 27 numeric.

- How to do it? For *"PIRI(781" FS NULL ETX* it should be **0B**

Comment: Stop using an "online CRC calculator", none of them implement this checksum method, and start writing code.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm trying to understand where to start. Do I have to find the byte for every symbol and then do XOR for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation incorrectly identifies the check value as a CRC. It is not. It is simply the exclusive-or of the noted bytes. The exclusive-or of 50 49 52 49 28 37 38 31 1c 00 03 is 0b. You then convert the 0b to hex (with an upper case B, i.e. 0B), and get 30 42.

Comment: You are right. But how do I do it? I always keep getting 1B in online calculators.

Comment: You simply use the exclusive-or operation in whatever language you are using. Simply "xor" in Delphi. As I said _this is not a CRC_. You cannot use online CRC calculators to calculate something that is not a CRC.